# Avoid having error when converting String to Integer in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to select a column that is defined as `VARCHAR`, as an `INTEGER` like this:

```
SELECT ID, CAST(Col1 as INT) as MyOutput FROM MyTABLE
```

The problem is when the column has an invalid format (that can't be converted to Integer) I want to set them to `NULL`. Is there a way to do this in DB2 ?

Comment: But why do you want to cast varchar as int? (Every time you want to do such cast, ask yourself if the table design should be updated instread.)

Comment: @jarlh the most obvious reason is "because the person writing this query may not have control over the source data".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to write your own conversion function that handles format exceptions, such as

```
create or replace function to_int_safe (str varchar(20)) 
returns int 
deterministic 
no external action contains sql 
begin 
  declare continue handler for sqlstate '22018' -- on conversion error
    return null; 
  return cast(str as int); 
end
```

then use it in your query:

```
SELECT ID, to_int_safe(Col1) as MyOutput FROM MyTABLE
```

Comment: do you remember what was the db2 version used to run the above snippet?

Comment: `create or replace function` was first introduced in Db2 for LUW 9.7; I'm pretty sure if you use simple `create function` it'll work in any version though.

Answer (score 0):

Following case statement determines whether a string contains a number that can be cast to integer. It seems to work so far. Nevertheless, it is complicated and too long. I mean it only checks whether a number can be converted to integer, not to mention how it would look for decimal numbers.

```
select case when ( -- no leading sign
                   ( instr(value,'-') = 0
                 and instr(value,'+') = 0 )
                   -- or one leading sign
                or ( left(ltrim(value),1) in ('-','+')
                 and instr(ltrim(value),'-',2) = 0
                 and instr(ltrim(value),'+',2) = 0 ) )
                 -- no spaces between digits
             and instr(trim(translate(value,'','+-')),' ') = 0
                 -- only numbers and sign
             and length(trim(translate(value,'','+-0123456789'))) = 0
                 -- no empty strings
             and length(trim(value)) <> 0
         then cast(value as int)
         else cast(null as int)
       end

from table (
  select '1  '  value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select '1.'   value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select 'a'    value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select '+1'   value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select '  -1' value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select '-  1' value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select '--1'  value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select '1 1'  value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select ''     value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select ' '    value from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select cast(null as char) value from sysibm.sysdummy1
) string_numbers;
```

It could be defined as function as well. However, this would not make it less ugly. It may be shortened or contain errors. Therefore, I prefer mustaccio's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522571/5498201), even though he has to deal with exception handling.